# how to switch over to parametrized way of coding

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've been using straight SQL queries in vb.net for insert, update and delete in my last project and I found lots of problems with straight query so i've finally decided that to switch to parametrized way of query, which is much more safe way of coding. Below is what i was using in my program, which i have quit now and trying to fully adopt the parametrized fashion of querying.

How i was programming with straight query is below:
I have a module where i have functions for Insert, Update and Delete, which were receiving values from all forms of application and working upon it and returning the data back. This is my module code:

```
#Region "Insertion"
''' <summary>
''' Simple Insert Function
''' </summary>
''' <param name="tblName"></param>
''' <param name="columns"></param>
''' <param name="parameters"></param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
''' 
Public Sub Insert(ByVal tblName As String, ByVal columns As String, ByVal parameters As String)
    Try
        cmdSql1.CommandText = "insert into " & tblName & "(" & columns & ") values (" & parameters & ")"
        cmdSql1.Connection = Connect()
        cmdSql1.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
#End Region
```

The data i was sending from forms is as followed, making the tblName, Columns and Parameters as string in to three groups as ("tblName", "Columns", "Parameters").

```
            Insert("CustomerInfo", "CustomerName, CustomerAddress, CustomerContact", "'" & txtCustName.Text.Trim & "','" & txtCustAddress.Text.Trim & "'," & txtCustContact.Text.Trim & "")
        MessageBox.Show("Customer Addedd Successfully")

        txtCustName.Clear()
        txtCustAddress.Clear()
        txtCustContact.Clear()
        txtCustName.Focus()
```

Same is the case was with select and update queries at module etc.

Now what i want to start my new project with parametrized one, but how to do this all in parametrized fashion. Pleassseee Guide me that how to leave the sql injection way back and join the parametrized one.

Comment: Are you trying to build a class that handle every possibile data related work for every possible table that you have in your db? This is really a big task and the results could be very disappointing. I suggest to dedicate some time to learn small and fast ORM libraries like Dapper http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: It looks like you are using one database connection which is always open. The preferred way is to create the connection, open it, perform the query, and close the connection immediately. The DB interface code handles that in an efficient way for you with [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Also, your database access code layer should not be interacting with the UI (as your MsgBox line does), instead you should catch the exception in the code which calls the DB access layer.

Comment: If i use simple parametrized queries on each form separately, so will it be fine to do: like making the ADO objects in a separate module (common for entire application ) with public specifiers and used them on all the forms and all the rest of the coding will be performed on each related form?

Comment: @ Andrew, not always open, i close it at the end of each query, using the finally part in Try Catch Block? 2). Secondly What does that mean Andrew that YOUR DATABASE ACCESS CODE LAYER SHOULD NOT BE INTERACTING WITH UI (AS YOUR MSGbOX LINE DOES) 3). thirdly, and how do i catch the exception in the code, do i used the msgBox line of code into the try block?